# Mapping array inside array with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a database in MongoDB and one of the props in the document contains an array. I'm trying to map the collection in the client-side using React using this code:

```js
<div>
    <h2>Recipes</h2>
    <ul>
        {this.state.recipes.map(recipe =>
            <li key={recipe._id}>
                {recipe.title}<br/>{recipe.category}<br/> 
                {recipe.ingredients}<br/>{recipe.preparation}
            </li>
        )}
    </ul>
</div>
```

`ingredients` prop is an array and I want to map it too. How can I do it?
Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: How the data looks like? Interested especially what the `recipe.ingerdients` contains.

Comment: I guess change`recipe.ingredients` to `{recipe.ingredients.map((ingredient) => (<p>{ingredient}</p>))}`

Comment: Hi, It would be better if you include all codes from that module you have problem with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just map it the same way you do with recipes

```
<div>
    <h2>Recipes</h2>
    <ul>
        {this.state.recipes.map(recipe =>
            <li key={recipe._id}>
                {recipe.title}<br/>
                {recipe.category}<br/> 
                {recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient => (
                   <span>{ingredient}</span>
                ))}
                <br/>{recipe.preparation}
            </li>
        )}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I've needed!
I'll just add that in the span tag the ingredient should be surrounded by { }

Answer (score 3):

just map it again

```
<div>
    <h2>Recipes</h2>
    <ul>
        {this.state.recipes.map(recipe =>
            <li key={recipe._id}>
                {recipe.title}<br/>
                {recipe.category}<br/> 
                {recipe.ingredients.map(k =>(
                   <span key={k._id}>{k}<span>
                 )<br/>
                {recipe.preparation}
            </li>
        )}
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
<div>
    <h2>Recipes</h2>
    <ul>
        {this.state.recipes.map(recipe =>
            <li key={recipe._id}>
                {recipe.title}<br/>{recipe.category}<br/> 
                 {  recipe.ingredients.map(ingredient => 
                    <span>{ingredient}</span>
                  )}                 
                <br/>{recipe.preparation}
            </li>
        )}
    </ul>
</div>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think ```forEach``` does not return anything, so it won't render?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `.map()` there by calling `recipe.ingredients.map()` as the following:

```
{this.state.recipes.map(recipe =>
    <li key={recipe._id}>
        {recipe.title}<br/>{recipe.category}<br/> 
        {
           recipe.ingredients.map((elem, index) => 
             <div key={index}>
                {elem /* or maybe elem['your-property-name'] if it's not a string */}
             </div>
           )
        }<br/>{recipe.preparation}
    </li>
)}
```

Also don't forget to add `key={index}` there to avoid the warning based on [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

Comment: You should add index as key to avoid the warning, you should add a unique key to avoid bugs on the ui. if you don't put a key, React automatically uses index as a key.
If ingredients is a Set of ingredients he should use key={elem}. If not he should use a unique key.